# Using glob to get txt and png files only from folder

Tags: python, glob

I am trying to get only text files and images from a folder be sent as an attachment so far I can only get it to work with one extension and I tried this below but it doesnt work

```
types = ('*.txt', '*.png')
files =glob.glob( os.path.join(path,types))

for f in files:
    part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
    part.set_payload( open(f,"rb").read() )
    Encoders.encode_base64(part)
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="%s"' % os.path.basename(f))
    msg.attach(part)
```

I got the following errors

```
files =glob.glob( os.path.join(path,types))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 73, in join
    elif isabs(b):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 58, in isabs
    return s != '' and s[:1] in '/\\'
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not tuple
```

Comment: Did you try passing it each string in turn?

Comment: This isn't how you use glob...

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams do you mean like this files =glob.glob( os.path.join(path,'*.txt', '*.png'))

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ what is the correct way?

Comment: Erm, no. To `glob.glob()`.